# How to apply flexbox styling on radio buttons with credit card icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in web development and I am working on a project where I have a payment form and I have to choose which credit card to use for payment . I have 3 radio buttons with credit card icons next to the buttons inside my form . What I want is the 3 options to be displayed in a row with space between each other via flexbox inside my payment form . However when I apply my code in my webpage I get the radio buttons above each card and I want to have them in format : radio button card(the card next to the button not down) .I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue . 
My code :

```css
.pay-container{

position:relative;
left:50%;
margin-top:400px;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
width:500px;
height:400px;
box-sizing:border-box; 
background:rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
padding:40px;  
 
} 

.pay-container input,select{

margin-bottom:20px;
width:100%; 
 
 
} 


.pay-container input[type=text]
{

border:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
outline:none;
height:30px;
color:#ffffff;
display:16px;
 
 
}


.pay-container select{
 
margin-top:20px;
padding:10px 0;
 
 
} 

.card-container{
 
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-start; 
 
} 

.card-container > div{

display:inline-block;
width:100px;
margin:10px;
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class = "pay-container">
    
 <form class = "pay">
 
 <label for "Firstname"> First Name </label>
 <input type = "text" name = "fname" id = "first" required>
 
 <label for "Lastname"> Last  Name </label>
 <input type = "text" name = "sname" id = "last" required>
  
    <label for "credit-card"> Choose a card </label><br/>

 <div class = "card-container">
    
      <div><input type = "radio" name = "card"><a href="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/"><img alt="Credit Card Logos" title="Credit Card Logos" src="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/images/discover_credit-card-logos/discover_logo_1.gif" width="57" height="36" border="0" /></a></div>
      <div><input type = "radio" name = "card"><a href="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/"><img alt="Credit Card Logos" title="Credit Card Logos" src="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/images/mastercard_credit-card-logos/mastercard_logo_4.gif" width="57 height="20" border="0" /></a></div>
      <div><input type = "radio" name = "card"><a href="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/"><img alt="Credit Card Logos" title="Credit Card Logos" src="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/images/visa_credit-card-logos/visa_logo_2.gif" width="57" height="36" border="0" /></a></div>
 
 </div>
 
 
 
 </form>

 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 100% width you have applied to your radio button inputs (under `.pay-container input, select`) is causing them to take up the entire width of the divs that contain them, which leaves no room for the credit card icons to sit next to them.  This bumps the icons down beneath the radio buttons.

(The easiest way to visualize this is to open Developer Tools and hover over one of your radio button inputs in the markup--you'll see the width of the radio button control highlighted visually in your browser.)

In the snippet below, I've moved the 100% width from the `.pay-container input, select` block to the `.pay-container input[type="text"]` block, so it will only apply to your text fields.  This leaves room for the icons to sit next to the radio buttons.

```css
.pay-container {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 400px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 40px;
}

.pay-container input,
select {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pay-container input[type="text"] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: 16px;
    width: 100%;
}

.pay-container select {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.card-container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pay-container">

    <form class="pay">

        <label for "Firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="first" required>

        <label for "Lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="sname" id="last" required>

        <label for "credit-card">Choose a card</label><br />

        <div class="card-container">

            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="card">
                <a href="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/">
                    <img alt="Credit Card Logos" title="Credit Card Logos" src="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/images/discover_credit-card-logos/discover_logo_1.gif" width="57" height="36" border="0" />
                </a>

            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="card">
                <a href="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/">
                    <img alt="Credit Card Logos" title="Credit Card Logos" src="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/images/mastercard_credit-card-logos/mastercard_logo_4.gif" width="57 height=" 20" border="0" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="card">
                <a href="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/"><img alt="Credit Card Logos" title="Credit Card Logos" src="http://www.credit-card-logos.com/images/visa_credit-card-logos/visa_logo_2.gif" width="57" height="36" border="0" />
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the style like:

```
.card-container > div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 3em;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px;
}
```